# Pattern on polynomials disguising as exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, extrapolation

Recently I've been looking at integer sequences that look like exponential at the first few terms but is actual polynomial, like these two sequences [[1]](https://oeis.org/A000127) [[2]](https://oeis.org/A000127). And there seems to be something interesting here.

Suppose we denote $S_m(n)$ to be *m*th-order polynomial sequence which $S_m(n) = 2^n$ for all non-negative integers up to *m*. So we have

$S_0(n) = 1$

$S_1(n) = n+1$

$S_2(n) = (n^2+n+2)/2$

$S_3(n) = (n^3+5n+6)/6$

$S_4(n) = (n^4-6n^3+23n^2-18n+24)/24$

And so on. For the first few cases that I've looked at, there seems to be a property that $$S_m(m+1)=2^{m+1} - 1$$

That is, the next term's always off by 1. I'm not sure if it's a general property or just a coincidence; People have been using these sequences to show "patterns in small n may not be legitimate".

Is there any way to prove (or disprove) this, other than the brute-force way of attempting a Gaussian elimination on the equations to find the suitable $S_m(m+1)$ such that the system of equations is solvable? It seems that these sequences have some relationships to combinatorics and binomial expansions (as the explicit form are also written in them, and the denomimator which goes as the factorial), but I'm not familiar with them.

Comment: Are you missing a $4n^2$ in the numerator of $S_3$?

Comment: I don't think so, for a simple case $S_3(1)$, $(1+5+6)/6=2$ while $(1+4+5+6)/6=16/6$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $S_m(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $m$ in $x$. Its $(m+1)^{th}$ order [finite difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference) vanishes. i.e

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m+1} (-1)^k  \binom{m+1}{k} S_m(m+1-k) = 0$$

This leads to
$$\begin{align}
S_m(m+1) &= -\sum_{k=1}^{m+1}(-1)^k \binom{m+1}{k} 2^{m+1-k}\\
&= 2^{m+1} - 2^{m+1}\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{m+1}{k} \left(-\frac12\right)^k\\
&= 2^{m+1} - 2^{m+1}\left(1 - \frac12\right)^{m+1}\\
&= 2^{m+1} - 1
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the first line...

Comment: @user158163 Given any function $f(x)$ and constant $h$, expression of the form $f(x+h)-f(x)$ is called the first order finite difference of $f(x)$. A $N^{th}$ order finite difference  is one obtained from $f(x)$ by taking finite difference $N$ times. The key is if $f(x)$ is a polynomial, each operation of taking finite difference returns a polynomial with degree one less. If you start from a polynomial of degree $m$, after taking finite difference $m+1$ times, you get $0$. The $2^{nd}$ line is the explicit expression for the $(m+1)^{th}$ finite difference when all the steps $h$ used is $1$.

Comment: Ahh, so it's taking many finite difference at once. I thought it's only taking one.